# Fitting logistic growth model. lme4 or nlme?

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear, growth-model

This is the first time I am using a nonlinear model. I am using a logistic growth model for analyzing tree growth pattern given by M. Bates and Pinheiro, 2000:.

$$ y = \frac{\phi_1}{1+e^{-(x-\phi_2)/\phi_3}}$$

In my dataset is repeated measure data in which $y$ is tree length and $x$ is time (day).

Now, I am confused about what is the packages and functions I should use to fit my data? nlmer function  in package lme4; lmer function in package nlme, or fuction nls?